# Opencart add custom page in admin folder getting error Page Not Found

Tags: php, opencart

Am creating a custom page called `no.tpl` in admin folder. It used for No-Order for selected customer.

In `view/template/sale/order_list.tpl`
Am creating a link for No Order page.

```
<a href="<?php echo $no; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="No Order" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> No Order</a>
```

And i called this link in `controller/sale/order.php`

```
$data['no'] = $this->url->link('sale/order/no', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

Then am creating a no.tpl file in `view/template/sale/`. That code is following

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
/*
some content here
*/
```

And finally and creating a controller this is the `path` `controller/sale/no.php`
And that page code following

```
class ControllerSaleNo extends Controller {
    private $error = array();
    public function index() {

           $data=$this->request->post;
           $customerId=$data['customer_id'];

        $this->sendMail($customerId);

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/no.tpl', $data));

        }
}
```

But am getting error link

> Page Not Found!
>   The page you are looking for could not be found! Please contact your administrator if the problem persists.

How can i clear this error and where i did mistake

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your link wants to access to `no` function in `order` controller:

```
$data['no'] = $this->url->link('sale/order/no', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

change it to:

```
$data['no'] = $this->url->link('sale/no', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

PS: your `controller/sale/no.php` has some errors, you must fix Them.

Comment: i got Permission Denied!  error thank you for replay @Mojtaba Sabeti

Comment: You're welcome, set correct permission via: admin panel / system / users / user groups

Comment: `Access Permission, Modify Permission` are selected

Comment: Any Solution Mojtaba Sabeti

Comment: I've tested, it works. are you sure you have set correct permission?

Comment: `Admin` this is my username, and my user group name Administrator. Here i give all permission.

Comment: `System->Users->User Group->Administrator`
`Edit-> `Access Permission` select all
`Modify Permission` select all
and click save

Comment: Any idea  Mojtaba Sabeti

Comment: which version of Opencart you are using? I tested on 2.3.0.2

Comment: Sorry for delay replay Mojtaba Sabeti, am using Version 2.0.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter a similar problem when accessing the administrative pagination of design, and when checking the code, the problem is as follows:

Direction : OpenCart/admin/controller/design/translation.php 
code in line 232

```
$pagination->url = $this->url->link('design/translation/history', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&page={page}', true);
```

The path of the web page has been redundant `/history` in it, so it did not work when it went to page 2

And when I delete it, everything works normally.